# MS Excel shows extra hyphen in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I just converted a file from PDF to excel. In each cell, it shows the correct value but when I press on the cell and look at the formula the hyphen is missing. I tried to fix this by adding the hyphen in but it just shows an extra one. How do I fix this? It is messing up all my lookups/merges.

[image]

This is without adding a hyphen notice how the Cell still shows 01206-NB but not the formula.
[image]

This is when I add a hyphen to the formula the initial one stays and I end up with two.

I have tried copy and paste specials but nothing works.

Edit:
When I press format cell
[image]

Comment: Here is my guess.  There is a character that the formula bar does not show that looks like a `-` but is not.  My guess is that if one put their cursor between the `N` and the `B` and hit the back space twice it would not delete the `6`.  It would delete the `N` and a hidden character.

Comment: @Lontiac When you right-click and hit Format Cell, can you show use that code to confirm there isn't some custom formatting happening? What is your language set to?

Comment: You can also use `=LEN(A16)` to check if there are special characters in your cell.

Comment: When I do =Len(A16) it shows 8 which is the amount without the hyphen. When I pressed back space twice it did not delete the hidden character. The format was originally in general I tried to change it to text to fix the issue but that did not do anything.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 7 without the hyphen?

Comment: @Lontiac no it is 7 without the `-`

Comment: You're right it is supposed to be 7 my bad.

Comment: Can you copy one of the problem cells here.  [edit] the post to include one.  Then we can test what character is invisible in the formula bar but visible in the cell.

Comment: You can use `=CODE(MID(A16,6,1))` to maybe get the ASCII code for the symbol.

Comment: Whenever I add the cell into the post it adds it as an image or text without the hyphen. The =CODE(MID(A16,6,1) returned a 45.

Comment: You can use =UNICODE(MID(A16,6,1)) to maybe get the UNICODE code for the symbol.

Comment: It is the "Soft Hyphen" (Unicode: 00AD)

Comment: Try this: `=SUBSTITUTE(A14,unichar(173),"-")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This answer was strongly polished by Scott Crane. Thanks a lot!**

[image]

Your data contains the **Soft Hyphen** (Unicode: 00AD = decimal 173).

## How to get rid of it?

### Method 1: Search and Replace

- Open **Search and Replace**
- Click in *Find what*
- Hold down the Alt key and ender 0173 with the **number pad** to put the soft hyphen into the box
- Leave "Replace" empty.

### Method 2: Formula

`=SUBSTITUTE(A16,UNICHAR(173),"")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I already updated the answer. But I would delete my answer, if you are willing to write one.

Comment: Nah, leave it.  It is very good.  You found the issue, I am just helping polish.